# Django Email alert after User creation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The user must receive a mail when the user was created if the post button was pressed in Django rest framework and below is my code. I'm Creating API for this project

**ERROR**

AttributeError at /api/User/
'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/User/
Django Version: 2.2.12
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'

```
class User(models.Model):
    
    CHOICES= (
    ('manager','Manager'),
      ('hr', 'HR'),
     ('hr manager','HR Manager'),
     ('trainee','Trainee')
)

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    joiningDate=models.DateTimeField(max_length=8)
    userrole=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname 

@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active and User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, is_active=True).exists():
        subject = 'Active account'
        mesagge = '%s your account is now active' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, mesagge, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.TextField()
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    endDate=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(User)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    Submitted_by=models.ForeignKey(default=None,related_name="SubmittedBy",to='User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ApprovedBy=models.ForeignKey(default=None,related_name="ApprovedBy",to='User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date=models.DateField()
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
    
    
class Client(models.Model):
    clientname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comapny=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=25,default=None)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.clientname
```

Comment: You created your own `User` model, and it has no `is_active` field...

Comment: Are you using your own custom User model that has a foreign key field to the django.contrib.auth.models User? I can really recommend [djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this kind of operations like email confirmation, resetting passwords and authorization

Comment: Hii! I'm not sure about this code..Where do I need to make changes

Answer (score 0):

Your custom user model has no `is_active` field, so `instance.is_active` as test makes not much sense. You can rewrite the check to:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).exists():
        subject = 'Active account'
        mesagge = '%s your account is now active' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, mesagge, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=True)
```

But that makes not much sense either, since for a `post_save`, we know that that record will be in the database. You can check if you created a *new* item with the `created` parameter:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        subject = 'Active account'
        mesagge = '%s your account is now active' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, mesagge, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=True)
```

Another approach is to add a field to your user model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # …,
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # …
```

I would however advise to inherit from the `AbstractUser` model, as is [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) this will already provide a basic model with some fields, and a manager that can be used to create users with a hashed password.

Comment: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column App_user.is_active does not exist
LINE 1: ... "App_user"."joiningDate", "App_user"."userrole", "App_user"...

Comment: Tried deleting my previous migrations but not able to connect to the DB

Comment: @ZoroD: I think you should not have removed the existing migrations. If you removed the migrations, you will need to clear the entire database (remove all tables), and make migrations and migrate from start.